# Skip jenkins stage if tag appears in the commit message

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-commit, commit-message

I'm trying to skip some stages in a Jenkins pipeline if something like #no_build or #no_unittest is in the commit message.

I wan't to skip the Unittest stage if #no_unittest is present in the commit message.

I saw that there is a solution using a script but is it possible to do it in a declarative way?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm build'
            }
        }
        stage('Unittest') {
            when{
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python unittest.py'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. The tags should be case sensitive, also "-" and "_" should be treated the same.

I tried putting changelog: #no_build but that didn't produce what was expected.
I'm not sure how to resolve the "-" and "_" being equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `changeLog` with the `when` condition. Example below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm build'
            }
        }
        stage('Unittest') {
            when{
                when { not { changelog '^.*#no_unittest.*$'} }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python unittest.py'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot that helped me! Also I managed to change the regex to fit my need for treating '-' and '_' the same and making it case insensitive. Here is my regex: `^(?i).*#no[-_]build.*$`

Comment: Hey @ycr ! I have a question about the `changelog '^.*#no_unittest.*$'`. I'm trying to set the regex in a variable as `def regex = /^.*#no_unittest.*$/` and using it as `changelog regex`. But Jenkins throws an error saying that `${regex} is not a valid regular expression. Illegal repetition near index 0` and pointing at `changelog regex`. Do you have any idea why could that be? As far as I know the regex is valid.

Comment: @K.Г. Why don't you create a new SO question with all the details?